# The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Hola estoy tratando de mandar un mail desde **ASP.NET** pero algo ahí me anda fallando, encontre que para usar el **mailer** debo no es mejor pasarle texto plano que variables , pero mi valirable es un **String**, no se si estoy pasando algo más por alto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación les dejo mi método completo

```js
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadRequest(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile, string name, string fn, string ft, int fs, string wiw, int dep, int cat, int schem, string email,
  string dat) {
  int status = 0;
  int seen = 0;
  int edit = 0;
  var send = "none";
  var appro = "none";
  int reject = 0;
  var exp = "30 days";
  byte[] bytes;
  using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream)) {
    bytes = br.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength);
  }
  string constr = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";
  using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {
    string query = "INSERT INTO Requests ([nameproject],[wiw],[format],[email],[fsize],[ftype],[fname]" +
      ",[categoriesid],[departmentid],[schemeid],[status],[expiration]," +
      "[seen],[edit],[createddate],[seendate],[answerdate],[rejected]" +
      ")" +
      " VALUES (@name,@wiw,@formato,@email,@size,@fType,@fname," +
      "@cat,@dep,@schem,@status,@exp,@seen,@edit,@dat,@seend,@ansd," +
      "@rej" +
      ")";
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query)) {
      cmd.Connection = con;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fType", ft);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@formato", bytes);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", fs);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wiw", wiw);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", cat);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dep", dep);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@schem", schem);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dat", dat);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@exp", exp);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@seen", seen);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edit", edit);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@seend", send);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ansd", appro);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rej", reject);
      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
    }
  }

  sendUploadRequestMail(email, wiw);

  return View();
}

public void sendUploadRequestMail( string email , string wiw ) {

        string to = "pushpoped@gmail.com" ;
        string from = email;
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
        message.Body = @"Using this new feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 25;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Host = "smtp.google.com";
        // Credentials are necessary if the server requires the client 
        // to authenticate before it will send e-mail on the client's behalf.
        // client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateTestMessage2(): {0}",
                        ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Se las dejo solo para que tengan contexto de donde vienen los datos, pero lo relevante es lo último. Gracias.

Comment: la variable email que estás pasando como parámetro parece que no cumple con el formato `string@string.string` ... compruébalo añadiendo una inspección a la variable

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,

Según veo, creo que has confundido el segundo parámetro que recibe la clase MailMessage. El primero es el remitente y el segundo es el destinatario.

Si vamos a la ayuda de Microsoft de la clase [MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/14k9fb7t(v=vs.110).aspx) vemos que el constructor que recibe 2 Strings espera dos cadenas con un formato determinado, y que de no cumplirlo lanzará una excepción de Formato, que es justamente la que te aparece a ti.
Si lo que quieres es añadir el cuerpo y el asunto del correo tienes que acceder a sus propiedades de la siguiente manera

```
message.Subject = "Asunto";
message.Body = "Cuerpo del mensaje";
```

Comment: Hola hize lo que dice la pagina de ayuda de mandarlos como variables **from** y **to**, pero nada. Lo editaré para que vean los cambios.

Comment: From y To tienen que ser String con formato de correo `string to = "pushpoped@gmail.com" ;`
 `string from = "correo@ejemplo.com";`
Así podemos usarlos en el constructor: 
`MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);`

 `message.Body= email;`

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer existe una incompatibilidad en el formato del parámetro enviado. Podrías representar el string en formato de correo electrónico, puedes intentar lo siguiente y ver que sucede.

```
string to = "pushpoped@gmail.com" ;
string from = email;//Tiene que ser un formato de correo valido ejemplo: micorreo@gmail.com
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
//Damos el formato a una direccion de correo electronico
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
message.From = new MailAddress(from);
```

Es la forma como lo tengo implementado y me funciona correctamente. Saludos.